# Is it possible to Export to a DLL a C++ class that inherits a base type from delphi BPL

Tags: c++, dll, c++builder, dllexport, bpl

I want to create a class `Gctable::TGcTable` that Inherits from `Pgaccess::TPgTable` and export it in a **.DLL**

Question: **Is it possible?**

I have such class definitions:

```
class DLL_EXPORT TGcTable : public Pgaccess::TPgTable
{
  ...
  public:
    __fastcall            TGcTable(TComponent* Owner);
    __fastcall virtual ~TGcTable(void);
    virtual void __fastcall Assign(TGcTable* other);
    void forceEmptyTable(void);
    void __fastcall EmptyTable();
    bool __fastcall Open(void);
  ...
}

class DLL_EXPORT SqlSchemaHelper
{
  ...
    static AnsiString extractSchema(const AnsiString& tablename);
    static AnsiString extractAlias(const AnsiString& tablename);
  ...
}
```

When I use the TDump utility to see the Exported members from the .dll 
That is what I see:

```
00008E40   18 0020 OT::GetTables(System::AnsiStringT<(unsigned short)0> const&, Pgaccess::TPgConnection*)
0000DC70   22 0021 Gcquery::TGcQuery::~TGcQuery()
00021050   44 0022 Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper::extractAlias(System::AnsiStringT<(unsigned short)0> const&)
00020D20   43 0023 Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper::extractSchema(System::AnsiStringT<(unsigned short)0> const&)
00021EC0   46 0024 Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper::isValidDataType(Data::Db::TFieldType)
00021340   45 0025 Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper::getDataTypeSQLString(Data::Db::TFieldType, int)
00020A80   42 0026 Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper::fastSplit(System::AnsiStringT<(unsigned short)0> const&, char)
000194A0   26 0027 Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper::SqlSchemaHelper(Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper const&)
00019460   24 0028 Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper::SqlSchemaHelper()
000194C0   27 0029 Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper::SqlSchemaHelper(Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper const&)
00019480   25 002A Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper::SqlSchemaHelper()
00019510   29 002B Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper::~SqlSchemaHelper()
00019530   30 002C Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper::~SqlSchemaHelper()
000194E0   28 002D Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper::operator=(Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper const&)
00019120   23 002E Gctable::TGcTable::~TGcTable()
00003E40   13 002F BulkWriter::getBufferSize() const
```

So it exported `Gctable::SqlSchemaHelper` class but not the `Gctable::TGcTable`

---

I believe that TPgTable is defined in a `pgdacvclXXX.bpl`

Comment: What I can see that the `Gctable::TGcTable::~TGcTable()` is actually exported (the second line from bottom). Are there any other methods? Note that only methods defined directly in TGcTable will be exported, not the methods inherited from the superclass `Pgaccess::TPgTable` (for that the class `Pgaccess::TPgTable` itself would have to be exported). Also note that inline methods (i.e. those defined inside of the header) are AFAIK *sometimes* not exported either, if they are not virtual (those can be directly instantiated in the executable using the definitions found in the header).

Comment: Hi @axalis , 
Thanks for explanation.
We used to compile this as .BPL and all functions were exported, now converting into .DLL and trying to understand what is happening here.
I added some public functions, to the description, I hope this will help.

Comment: Where are the TGcTable methods defined? Are they in a separate.cpp file or in the same header (inlined) - as said, if the compiler decided to inline them, they might not be exported from the DLL. You can also try to check the DLL with a different tool for exportd, for example `dumpbin /exports` or `depends.exe` (that one needs to be downloaded separately from Mcrosoft)

Comment: @axalis : TGcTable methods defined in `.cpp` file ( same as in `SqlSchemaHelper` );  `depends.exe` provides the same set of exported symbols.